# Should I re-caulk window drip edge?

Tags: caulking

I've noticed that the caulking along the drip edges of several windows at my home are cracking (see attached photo). I had a window repair man take a look and he said that this was merely cosmetic and not something I needed to be concerned with getting repaired, as he said no rain or moisture can get in, despite the cracks.

Can anyone confirm if this is indeed the case? Newbie here and hoping to get a second opinion.

[image: Lintel over window with some cracking]

Comment: That white piece with the brown rust marks at the top of the window looks to be a steel/iron lintel - not really a drip edge.  It acts like a beam to support the weight of the bricks or stone above the window.  It is highly unlikely rain could get in there.  But sealing it would cause no harm that I can see.

Answer (score 2):

Both bugs and moisture (in the case of humidity) can get in very easily. Also, if there's any slope toward the door, rain water can find its way in.

Do the right thing; peel off the old caulking, clean the area with isopropyl alcohol, and apply new caulking.

For the tiny amount of money and time it will take, even just the appearance factor will be worth it.